# Among these two in my ps output, which real-time process will be preempted over the other by linux?

Tags: process, ps, real-time, priority

I have got some idea from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8887531/which-real-time-priority-is-the-highest-priority-in-linux  about how the real time priority values assigned to different identifiers in the kernel mean different (opposite) things.

But I'm still not clear on the interpretation of values in the RTPRIO column of my ps output. Does higher numerical value mean higher priority or is it the opposite.

Specifically, given ps ouput below: whether **rcub/0** (RTPRIO=1) is higher priority than (i.e. can preempt) **migration/0** (RTPRIO=99) or is it the other way around.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to [proc man](https://linux.die.net/man/5/proc):

Priority is the amount of time that a process waited-for children have been scheduled in kernel mode, it is measured in clock ticks. A value in the range 19 (low priority) to -20 (high priority). Process can be running under real-time or non-real time priorities.

- For processes running a real-time scheduling policy (i.e. the scheduler is the kernel component that decides which runnable process will be executed by the CPU next. Each process has an associated scheduling policy and a static scheduling priority, sched_priority; these are the settings that are modified by `sched_setscheduler()`. The scheduler makes it decisions based on knowledge of the scheduling policy and static priority of all processes on the system.), this is the negated scheduling priority, minus one; that is, a number in the range -2 to -100, corresponding to real-time priorities 1 to 99.
- For processes running under a non-real-time scheduling policy, this is the raw nice value (i.e. the scheduling priority of the process, process group, or user, as indicated by which and who is obtained with the getpriority() call and set with the setpriority() call.) as represented in the kernel. The kernel stores nice values (i.e. column `NI` in the `ps` table as numbers in the range 0 (high) to 39 (low), corresponding to the user-visible nice range of -20 to 19.